Azure Function sync calls
We are working in a coupled of azure functions chained, they are not durable functions but Azure Functions in a Premium Plan chained by writing in an Azure Service Bus Queue. Some of them make calls to external services. We have the following behavior with those calls:

When the function sends the request to the external service it waits for a time, if there is no response it continues with the next step: mark the process as finished and triggering the next function by writing to a queue.
After the function marks the process as finished, it sometimes receives responses from some requests that didn't response on time and again get the responses and process it and at the end tries to update the database again and trigger the next function.

Now, what are the best approaches to solve this?
Is there any way to make the function wait until it receives all the responses and then trigger the next function ? Does it worth it ?
Should we need to consider move the process to Durable Functions? Will the chained patter fulfill the requirements?
Thanks!!
We have tried to wait for the request and to keep the function listening without moving to the next step.
We expect to get the responses and then move it to the next step


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree
As you see, Azure Function is not suitable for web.
HTTP is a stateless protocol. And Function can only live 10 or 30 minutes, after that, function will forget all.
